# How to get each elements separately in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in node.js . Actually I'm trying to send an arrayList from android device and trying to print result of separate indexes but I'm unable to achieve this as `js` doesn't support associative array concept.

The data sent to the server is in `{names:'[a,b]'}` format so my question is how can I get each elements i.e 'a' & 'b' separately

Comment: *associative array* -> Object / Map / 2d Array

Comment: Sir could you please provide the syntax @JonasW.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is the format

```
{names:'[a,b]'}
```

Then this will give you the names array

```
<objectName>.names.split('[')[1].split(']')[0].split(',')
```

Comment: Sending the object like that will actually put overhead on your server,
the above line of code is actually converting `'[a,b]'` to `['a','b']`, that's an extra computation which is unnecessary. I think Ashish's answer was a better approach. You should send the object from the android app in the correct format.

Answer (score 3):

You should send array as, { name : ['a', 'b'] } , without quotes around array.
You can get indexes with below syntax

```
data = { name : ['a', 'b'] } // this is from device
```

Array.prototype.map

```
data.name.map(function(element){
    console.log(element);
})
```

You can read more about map here, [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

forEach

```
data.name.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element);
})
```

both will print a b

Answer (score 2):

Consider to pass your object as `{name: ['a', 'b']}` (as Ashish mentioned above), then you can use ES6 syntax (in case you use the latest LTS node version) to destruct your object:

`const { name } = {name: ['a', 'b']}; const { a, b } = name`

If you still want to receive your object as `{name: '[a, b]'}`, you'll have to parse your string array fiirst.